# SQL join 2 tables where data is not intersecting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, one for storing a post and the other for users that has liked the post.

I want to fetch the posts only where user has not liked it.

Example

**Posts Table:**

post_id, title

**Like Table:**

like_id, post_id, user_id

I only want the list of posts where user has not liked it.

What should be the SQL query?

Comment: LEFT JOIN etc. Or NOT EXISTS.

Comment: MySQL [intersect](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-intersect/) simulate/emulate

Answer (score 0):

SELECT POSTS.post_id
FROM POSTS
WHERE POSTS.post_id NOT IN (SELECT LIKE.post_id
FROM LIKE,POSTS
WHERE POSTS.post_id=LIKE.post_id);

Comment: MySQL does not understand the SQL standard `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT` you need to simulate/emulate [those](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-intersect/).. Also if it would work in MySQL this query is also wrong because it should have been `INTERSECT` instead off `EXCEPT`